# Put two dots above beta

Tags: relation-symbols

I try to put two dots above a beta ancient greek character like this
`\"β`
But a beta symbol is too tall, so the dots are printed on the beta symbol. How can I move dots up?
The dots should go above the symbol.
Using math formula I can realized this something like this

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \[\stackrel{..}{\beta}\]
    \end{document}
```

But, how can I got it without using math formula?

My setup is

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{float}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{New Athena Unicode}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Cyrillic]
```

Comment: Please tell us more about the mysterious `β` symbol: Is it maybe supposed to be the (mostly German) "ess-zett" (aka "scharfes S") character? Or is a text-mode beta character? (I gather it's not supposed to be the math-mode character `\beta`...)

Comment: Your code is already perfectly fine to me. I can see two dots above the `beta` symbol. Please be more specific.

Comment: Yes, two dots are above the beta, but may be too high. And it is not a math text, I suppose to avoid the math formulas. It is a simple diacritic symbol. I try to find charset what contains beta with to dots but don't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It mostly depends on how you input beta. Here's a possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\newcommand{\betaumlaut}{%
  {\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\accdialytika{b}}%
}

\begin{document}

\betaumlaut

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `fontspec` and Unicode fonts with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can (provided the Greek font is good) do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{Gentium}

\begin{document}

{\greekfont\"β}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, New Athena Unicode is not among the “good” fonts, because if I try the above code with this font I get

[image]

For the particular font you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{newathu}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*5_7,
  BoldFont=*Bold5_7,
  ItalicFont=*Italic5_7,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldItalic5_7,
]

\newcommand{\manualdialytika}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\symbol{"A8}\cr\noalign{\kern-1ex}#1\cr}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

{\greekfont\manualdialytika{β}}

\end{document}
```

(How you load New Athena Unicode depends on whether you installed it as a system font, which I chose not to do.)

[image]

Comment: I just use New Athena Unicode font. I install font, define font family \newfontfamily\greekfont{New Athena Unicode} and using it {\greekfont διᾱϰόσιοι}.

Comment: @AlexE. I added how to do it in a clean way, if the Greek font is good and an “unclean way” otherwise.